# Is there a way to write a custom React component that will accept Chakra UI style props?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

Consider I have this custom React component.

```js
import { FormControl, FormLabel, Input } from '@chakra-ui/react'

export interface CustomTextInputProps {
  label: string
  value: string
}

export const CustomTextInput: React.FC<CustomTextInputProps> = ({
  label,
  value,
}) => {
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <FormLabel>{label}</FormLabel>
      <Input value={value} />
    </FormControl>
  )
}
```

I am looking to include this component in my application as style its position each time it is instantiated. For example, I could do this by wrapping it in a Box.

```js
import { Box } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { CustomTextInput } from './custom-text-input'

export const ApplicationForm: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Box mt={5}>
      <CustomTextInput />
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Is there a way to write a component in a way that it will accept Chakra UI style props passed to it directly? The idea would be to do away with the additional Box usage just for layout and end up with something like this.

```js
import { CustomTextInput } from './custom-text-input'

export const ApplicationForm: React.FC = () => {
  return <CustomTextInput mt={5} />
}
```

I've looked in to the [Chakra factory function](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/features/chakra-factory#chakra-factory-function) but ideally, I'm looking to for a solution within the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

## child custom component

```
import { forwardRef,Box, Button, BoxProps } from "@chakra-ui/react";
export const FloatButton = forwardRef<BoxProps, "div">((props, ref) => (
  <Box px="4" py="5" rounded="none" shadow="lg" ref={ref} {...props}>
    <Button>like this?</Button>
  </Box>
));
```

## parent component

```
import { Link } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { FloatButton } from "../components/atoms/buttons/FloatButton";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <Link href="/projects">project index</Link>
      <Link href="/users/1">users detail</Link> */}
      <FloatButton bg="#ff0">like this?</FloatButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yutAR.png)